# Plus equals returning error in c++

Tags: c++

I'm having problems with the '+=' in this code. I can't figure out why the compiler complains, returning the error "expected a ';'". I'm sure this is a really easy fix but I'd be really grateful if someone could let me know where i'm going wrong.

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES

#include <iostream>;
#include <cmath>;
using namespace std;


double R = 15;
double Qr = 61.17;
double A = 2.47e08;
double Tp = 447;
double Q = 10000;
double t = 0;
double hb = 0;
double hbnew = 0;
int t1 = 300;
int t2 = 400;
double ph_tot = 0;

int main() {

     for (t = 0; t < Tp; t++) {

        double hb = (0.5*R + ((Qr / ((A*R) / Tp)*t)));
        double angle = t / (2 * M_PI);
        double hm = cos(angle);


        if (t1 < t && t < t2) {
            double hbnew = hb - (Q / ((A*R) / Tp)*t);
            double ph2 = 9180 * (hbnew - hm)*Q;
            double ph_tot += ph2;
            cout << "Power generated" << ph2 << endl;

        }

        else {
            double hbnew = hb;
        }


    }

system("pause");
return 0;

}
```

Comment: please add the error you get (did you read it?)

Comment: You keep declaring *new* variables instead of using the existing ones.

Comment: This is **way** to much code for such a simple question. Chop it, and keep chopping until the error goes away. Then, if it isn't obvious what the problem is, undo the last chop and continue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is because you use it in an intialisation that redefines a local variable having the same name than a global variable:

```
        double ph_tot += ph2;
```

For an intialization you have to use `=`  (otherwise you would add something to an undefined value).

But if you want to add something to your global variable, just remove the type:

```
        ph_tot += ph2;
```